# How to create Menu in HTML5 and CSS3 like Circles?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am confused that how can i create the menu like circles and sub-circles in HTML5/CSS3?

Explanation:

```
<ul>
    <li>Circle-1
        <ul>
            <li>Circle-1.1</li>
            <li>Circle-1.2</li>
            <li>Circle-1.3</li>
            <li>Circle-1.4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Circle-2
        <ul>
            <li>Circle-2.1</li>
            <li>Circle-2.2</li>
            <li>Circle-2.3</li>
            <li>Circle-2.4</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Circle-3</li>
    <li>Circle-4</li>
</ul>
```

This is my hierarchy of Parent Circle and Child Circle.

I would like to Create Menu something like When I click on Each Circle It should be show other sub-menu options as a Connected Circles.

Example 1
[image]

Can anyone give me suggetion how to achieve this functionality or is there any Javascript API available to achieve same as Example 1

Comment: Use `border-radius` in CSS3

Comment: @TusharGupta I am try using CSS to Show/Hide Simple DIV on Hover of parent Circle DIV. But not sure how to show like in given image.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have created a similar implementation in the past using jquery, you might find it useful.
It can be used as a jquery plugin,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.menu').roundMenu({
        /*
        menuSize: "50px",
        optionSize: "30px",
        distance: "70px",
        span: "180",
        offset: "0",
        isMenuRound: true,
        isOptionsRound: true,
        animate:true,
        onShow:function(i){alert("showed :"+i);},
        onHide:function(i){alert("hidden :"+i);}*/

    });
```

there is also a fiddle about it,
http://jsfiddle.net/melc/Qv6Y6/

also tested it with sub menus and it works (fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/rX8fJ/)

unfortunately not much documenation but try to spot the way it is being used, it has some props

Comment: Wow!!! that is i want. It is too much pretty. One question any dependency if i use it and it is an opensource?

Comment: thank you i will be try to add this functionality to my site I hope it will be fit properly.

Answer (score 1):

example how to create a circle in fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BQKSc/

CSS

```
div {
    width: 10em;
    height: 10em;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5em;
    -moz-border-radius: 5em;
    border:5px solid red;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 4.5em;
}
```

HTML

```
<div><p>CIRCLE</p></div>
```